# Lua--parse text from .txt file and store the values

Tags: lua

I receive the following error when I try to run my code:

```
lua:readFile.lua:7: attempt to call method 'split' (a nil value)
```

I am teaching myself Lua and doing some exercises. I am trying to parse out the individual values in a text file and then do stuff with them. I can open the file and if I don't try to parse out the values I can print the contents.
I have tried, separately:

```
dollars, tickets = line:split(" ")  
dollars, tickets = line:split("(%w+)", " ")
```

Along with several other iterations I cannot recall at this point.

Here is my code:

```
myfile = io.open("C:\\tickets.txt", "r")

if myfile then
print("True")    --test print
for line in myfile:lines() do
    local dollars, tickets = unpack(line:split(" "))
    print(dollars)
end
end
print("Done")  --test print
myfile:close()
```

Here is the content of the tickets.txt file in its entirety:

250 5750
  100 28000
  50 35750
  25 18750

I am obviously missing something in the split method but I do not know enough to know what.

Regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The string library in Lua doesn't include a 'split' function.  You will have to implement one yourself (there's examples on the Lua wiki), or use Lua's pattern matching functionality to parse out the pieces.  For example, you could do something like this:

```
local dollars, tickets = line:match("(%d+) (%d+)")
```

Comment: I guess I don't understand. From the Lua wiki page [link]http://lua-users.org/wiki/SplitJoin. Is the split function in there not what I should be using? In any event, I used the code you provided and it returns what I need, so thank you.

Comment: You can use the split function they describe there, but you need to manually add it to your string library.  About 1/4 of the way down that page they show a few different implementations of split. You could copy one of these into a Lua file and put the function into your string table:  string.split = <wiki code goes here>.  The just require that Lua file into your script.  Make sure you pick a split implementation that works with the version of Lua you are using.

Answer (score 3):

If you only want to read numbers from a file and do not want to enforce them to be two on each line, you can use this code:

```
while true do
  local dollars,tickets = myfile:read("*n","*n")
  if dollars==nil or tickets==nil then break end
  print(dollars)
end
```

Comment: Thank you. The code you provided works as well. I already marked Mike's answer as the answer and I am not cool enough to upvote yours. Much appreciated, in any event.